# Auto-size ImageView (besides TextView) and parent height, while persevering aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, aspect-ratio

I am struggling with newbie question.

I have a layout defined like this: (it is used as listview item)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/articleSmallImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsIntroText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What i want to achieve is this: 
Parent layout height to resize according to the highest child. In this case if TextView is higher then ImageView, ImageView aspect ratio should be intact, with max width possible, and if ImageView i higher then TextView, again, width should be maximal, and parent should have height as ImageView.

[image]

This is actually screenshot from my app, running on JB 4.3. and is looks as expected. But on ICS 4.0.3, 4.0.4 it looks like this.

[image]

I cannot see any reason why ImageVIew is not filling that blank space.

Help..

Comment: When you use ``weight`` in Horizontal linear layout you always set `width` to ``0dp``

Comment: I've set 0dp width value, but no change for ICS

Answer (score 0):

Try the value fitXY for scaleType. Btw unless I'm missing something, I think your LinearLayout1 is useless. Also, like YouYou said.. If a weight has been set in a vertical layout, the height should be 0dp and in a  horizontal linear layout, the width should be set to 0dp for better performance.

Comment: LinearLayout1 contains more then one TextView, but those items are set to GONE visibility (i am expecting request from client to put them to VISIBLE state at some point), but their presence is irrelevant for problem i described.
Now, i have changed scaleYpe to fitXY and as i expected, image is streched (width is filled), but height is small (like in second screenshot). And i have changed width to 0dp.

Its is working on JB although, but not on ICS. Something is wrong with adjustViewBound on ICS

Comment: set the Height of the `ImageView` to `match_parent`. It's not scaling right now, because the max height it is trying to use is the image's height.